# Install R from source

Tags: r

I'm trying to install R from source in my home directory on a server running CentOS.

**I do not have root rights**, and I'm not permitted to write to `usr/local/include/'.

I use the following code:

```
 wget http://cran.rstudio.com/src/base/R-3/R-3.2.0.tar.gz
 tar xvf R-3.2.0.tar.gz
 cd R-3.2.0
 ./configure --prefix=$HOME/R
```

In configuration step, I get error

```
configure:error:--with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not available
```

In my understanding, it tells me that readline library is not available.
So I try to install readline.
I downloaded tar.gz file. and then I use the following command

```
 tar xvf readline-6.3.tar.gz
 cd readline-6.3
 ./configure --prefix=$HOME/readline
 make
 make install
```

Things are fine, and there's an additional folder in my home directory named "readline".

When I go back and try to configure R again, I still get the same error message. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please clue us in as to which OS you are using.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm working on a Linux cluster, CentOS in particular.

Comment: The only obvious thing which comes to mind is try doing `sudo su` then doing the install afterwards.  You may need to have admin rights to complete the installation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Unfortunately, I cannot sudo anything as I don't have such rights.

Comment: Try with `./configure LDFLAGS="-L/$HOME/readline"` (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Compilation-flags)

Comment: @MartinMorgan I will try what you suggested with configure. Unfortunately, I couldn't even write to ~/usr/local/lib

Comment: @Pascal When I "make install", I get message "cannot create regular file `/usr/local/include/readline': Permission denied"

Comment: See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149451/install-r-in-my-own-directory) for a possible duplicate.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I followed the exact post. But I couldn't even make through configuration. The reason is that there's no readline library. I checked system library, and I'm sure realine is not there.

Comment: @Pascal I still get the same error.  Do you mean I only change the `./configure...` line when configuring R, without making any change to the way I install readline?

Comment: @Pascal Then what I did is exactly the same as you. Is it possible that you already have readline in your system library, so "LDFLAGS" is not used?

Comment: OK. This recognizes the local readline, but leads to another error (at least for me): `./configure LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/readline/lib -I$HOME/readline/include" --prefix=$HOME/R`. Let's see if you get an error.

Comment: @Pascal When I `make`, I get errors after entering directory $HOME/R-3.2.0/src/unix,  It says something in sys-std.c file is undeclared

Answer (score 1):

Try using these flags for your ./configure script

```
CXXFLAGS="-ggdb -pipe -Wall -pedantic -I/path/readline/6.3/include"
CPPFLAGS="-I/path/readline/6.3/include"
LDFLAGS="-L/path/readline/6.3/lib"
```

Then if you get an error about X11, set --with-x=no and try again.