# Trouble with library readline while installing R

Tags: r, linux, debian, readline

I'm trying to install R 3.2.3 from source. When I run `./configure` I get the error:

```
configure: error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not available
```

Just before that, there is:

```
checking readline/history.h usability... no
checking readline/history.h presence... no
checking for readline/history.h... no
checking readline/readline.h usability... no
checking readline/readline.h presence... no
checking for readline/readline.h... no
checking for rl_callback_read_char in -lreadline... no
checking for main in -lncurses... no
checking for main in -ltermcap... yes
checking for rl_callback_read_char in -lreadline... no
checking for history_truncate_file... no
```

So I guess the problem is that the library readline is not installed on my system. As I don't have root access (I'm at work), I tried to install it locally. Here is what I did:

```
cd
mkdir readline
```

After downloading the tar.gz in `/tmp`:

```
cd /tmp
tar -zxvf readline-6.3.tar.gz
cd readline-6.3
./configure --prefix=$HOME/readline

make
make install
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/readline
```

This seems to have worked well but I still can't install R, I get the same error. How can I tell R where to find readline?

By the way, my OS is Debian 8, if this helps.

Comment: Check out the comments in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158570/install-r-from-source.  If this works, this post should potentially be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Following the comments, I tried
`./configure LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/packages/lib -I$HOME/packages/include/readline" --prefix=$HOME/R/R-3.2.3`
This seems a little better since I don't have the first error anymore, but I still have this series of `no`. The process goes on a little longer, until I have a long list of errors like `config.status: creating Makeconf
gawk: symbol lookup error: /home/user/packages/lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: UP`

Comment: Good that you got past the first error, have you googled for the new error ?

Comment: Adding `CPPFLAGS=-I$HOME/packages/include` I don't get the `checking` errors (it finds the headers apparently). But I still get the `undefined symbols` errors.

Comment: Have a look at the following links to see if it helps: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/39731 or this https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=179521

Comment: The problem of your link was due to the version of libreadline, if I understand correctly. My version is 6.3, but I don't know if that is the problem. I also have the errors
`checking for rl_callback_read_char in -lreadline... no
checking for main in -lncurses... no`
but I don't know what this means.